# Indent first line after section title in scrbook

Tags: koma-script, indentation, scrbook

I have search a lot about this with no luck at all. So here I am asking for help. 
I would like to indent the first line of paragraphs after the section title with the same indentation as the title itself. But after a lot of tryouts, and nothing similar to what I need, I am getting desperate.
This is my MWE, actually, my Minimal Not Working Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareSectionCommand[
    afterindent=true,
    indent=10mm,
    beforeskip=10mm,
    afterskip=5mm,
]{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[75]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

[image]
While I am searching for output like the following one, where the first line after the section title keeps the indentation of the title above it.
[image]
In the Koma-script manual, I could find how to control the vertical separations, or if there is an indentation or not at all, but what I didn't find was how to set a quantity for the first paragraph indentation. I don't even know if this is in any way straight forward or even possible using the scrbook class.

Answer (score 1):

`indentfirst.sty` does the trick

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[75]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But actually Identfirst doesn't solve the issue with setting values for the indentation. I think it just activate the indentation of the first line without allowing to set the value of that indention. Thank you anyway for the help.

Comment: `\parindent` value as same as `indentfirst` value...

Comment: I have been reading the identfirst documentation, which indeed, is very scarce. An I didn't see how to do it. Do you have any idea of how to achieve that. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: The following suggestion uses internal commands, so it may break in the future.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}
\recalctypearea% <- added, because of the fontsize change
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}

\DeclareSectionCommand[
    indent=10mm,
    afterindent=true,
    beforeskip=10mm,
    afterskip=5mm,
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    indent=15mm,
    afterindent=true,
    beforeskip=15mm,
    afterskip=5mm,
]{subsection}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlength\firstindent

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@afterheading}
  {\if@afterindent \else}
  {\if@afterindent \hspace{\firstindent}\else}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\newcommand*\setfirstindent[1]{%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{scr@#1@sectionindent}
    {\setlength{\firstindent}{-\parindent}}
    {\setlength{\firstindent}{\dimexpr\@nameuse{scr@#1@sectionindent}-\parindent\relax}}%
}
\makeatother
\AddtoDoHook{heading/postinit}{\setfirstindent}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\lipsum[75]\par\lipsum[75]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[75]\par\lipsum[75]
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\lipsum[75]\par\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very nice hack, specially the second one. It seems to be quite close to the one needed. Do you know how to reset to the document indentation of the other paragraphs following the first one. In the example seems that the second paragraph keeps the indentation of the first one. Thanks a lot for the code. It is very nice.

Comment: @MickFM See my updated answer.

Comment: `\firstindent=\skip64
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.25 
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> `

Comment: Trying the updated code, the above error shows up several times. It looks like some error with the units! Is there anything that I could do to fix it? Thanks again for the help. (Using koma-script 3.28 - Updated TexLive 2019).

Comment: There was a bug  in `\Ifundefinedorrelax` in KOMA-Script 3.28, see https://komascript.de/release3.28 (German). This is fixed in 3.29 (https://komascript.de/release3.29, not yet on CTAN). Nevertheless I have replaced `\Ifundefinedorrelax` by `\scr@ifundefinedorrelax` in the examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now compiles, but unfortunately, the indentation is applied to all the paragraphs in the section, not just the first one :(.

Comment: Do you want a parskip instead parindent for the next paragraphs? Then use class option `parskip=full` or `parskip=half` or similar (see the documentation) in the updated example on the top of my answer.

Comment: Note that in your picture with the desired result (second picture in question) the other paragraphs are indented too.

Comment: That may not be the best example, sorry. It is seen more clearly in the fourth page of the example (section 1.2.1.1): https://www.usc.gal/export9/sites/webinstitucional/gl/centros/ciedus/doutoramento/descargas/modelo_tese/Exemplo-de-texto.pdf

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the relation of parskip with the horizontal identation. As I see it in the manual, It seems to be an option related with the vertical spacing between paragraphs.

Comment: I have removed my old suggestions. The remaining one should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. This one works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get two different solutions. The first one thanks to @esdd, and the other one by mail.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareSectionCommand[
    indent=20mm,
    afterindent=true,
    beforeskip=3ex,
    afterskip=0.5ex,
]{section}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlength\firstindent

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@afterheading}
  {\if@afterindent \else}
  {\if@afterindent \hspace{\firstindent}\else}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\newcommand*\setfirstindent[1]{%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{scr@#1@sectionindent}
    {\setlength{\firstindent}{-\parindent}}
    {\setlength{\firstindent}{\dimexpr\@nameuse{scr@#1@sectionindent}-\parindent\relax}}%
}
\makeatother
\AddtoDoHook{heading/postinit}{\setfirstindent}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter Title}
        \lipsum[75] 

        \lipsum[75]
    \section{Section Title}
        \lipsum[75] 

        \lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

The second one (doesn't need xpatch package):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    indent=20mm,
    beforeskip=3ex,
    afterskip=0.5ex,
    afterindent=true,
    runin=false,
]{section}

% Change the paragraph indent after the sectio:
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{\global\parindent=20mm}

\makeatletter
\def\@afterheading{%
    \@nobreaktrue
    \everypar{%
        \if@nobreak
        \@nobreakfalse
        \clubpenalty \@M
        \if@afterindent
        \else
        {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
        \fi
        \global\parindent=\scr@parindent% reset the paragraph indent
        \else
        \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
        \everypar{}%
        \fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \lipsum[75] 

    \lipsum[75]
    \section{Section Title}
    \lipsum[75] 

    \lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

Running nice now. Thank you!